# Get-S3Object returns keyprefix (folder) itself?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using S3 Powershell api (Get-S3Object) to retrieve files from S3, the thing is that the api works in a strange way.

I run the following command first:

```
 Get-S3Object -BucketName "tools-bucket" -keyprefix "Rollback/ust1twastool01a"
```

It returns this list:

```
ETag         : "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
Key          : Rollback/ust1twastool01a/
LastModified : 11/7/2016 3:24:13 PM
Owner        : Amazon.S3.Model.Owner
Size         : 0
StorageClass : STANDARD

ETag         : "e0ada177422c1fe4d9bd9801636f4e8a"
Key          : Rollback/ust1twastool01a/Rollback_Kit.txt
LastModified : 11/7/2016 3:25:00 PM
Owner        : Amazon.S3.Model.Owner
Size         : 626
StorageClass : STANDARD
```

The first one is the keyprefix itself which is a folder. Then I run the command with another keyprefix:

```
Get-S3Object -BucketName "tools-bucket" -keyprefix "Rollback/autopatch"
```

It returns this:

```
ETag         : "4c3723148b9fb78d5b182c72aa6f1866-62"
Key          : Rollback/autopatch/2016-08-30_21-15-17_server-1.1.20558_client-1.1.20518.zip
LastModified : 8/30/2016 5:18:43 PM
Owner        : Amazon.S3.Model.Owner
Size         : 323772907
StorageClass : STANDARD

ETag         : "bfc65b2cde2c3f24a2086ca503270a54"
Key          : Rollback/autopatch/buildRecords.txt
LastModified : 8/30/2016 5:19:44 PM
Owner        : Amazon.S3.Model.Owner
Size         : 53
StorageClass : STANDARD
```

This time, the keyprefix is not returned. I don't quite figure it out why it happens

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when you create a folder in the console.  They're placeholders.  They aren't needed unless you need to navigate "into" a folder manually to upload objects.  Your workaround is to skip objects ending in `/` that are zero-byte objects.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/about-using-console.html#welcome-folder-concept

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I've found a workaround but just curious